# Changing width of particular column in Dataframe

Tags: html, css, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas Dataframe with 10-11 Columns. I want to convert this dataframe into html using pd.to_html(index=False, border=0). However, I want to change CSS of returned table.
Can we change column width of dataframe itself, or format  tags of returned table from pd.to_html()

Html Code for expected table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th width="5%">A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th width="3%">D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently after pd.to_html() , i am getting this table

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: right;">
           <th>A</th>
           <th>B</th>
           <th>C</th>
           <th>D</th>
           <th>E</th>
           <th>F</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

It will be great if tr tag will be removed from output after thead tag as its is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can use the styler of df:

```
df_html = df.style.set_table_styles({
    'A': [{'selector': 'thead tr',
           'props': [('width', '5%')]}],
    'D': [{'selector': 'thead tr',
           'props': [('width', '3%')]}],
})

print(df_html.render(sparse_index=True))
```

The output is pretty verbose:

```
<style type="text/css">
#T_0167d_ thead tr.col0 {
  width: 5%;
}
#T_0167d_ thead tr.col3 {
  width: 3%;
}
</style>
<table id="T_0167d_">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >C</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >D</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >E</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col5" >F</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```